# If checked append var else remove var

Tags: jquery, append, var

I am trying to create a list (spans) using label text of checkbox inputs. 
It appends fine, but the remove is not working.

```
$('#device_type_list li input').change(function(){
  var response = $('label[for="' + this.id + '"]').text();
  var device = $('<span>' + response + '</span>');
  if(this.checked){
    $('#device_filter_summary').append(device); 
  } else {
    $('#device_filter_summary').find(device).remove();
  }
});
```

EDIT: here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kirkbross/9jr3v5hq/

Comment: you can just do `$('#device_filter_summary').find('span').remove();`

Comment: Your code looks OK. Try breaking it into smaller pieces that you can see in debug. var summary = $('#device_filter_summary'); var thisDevice = summary.find(device); var thisDevice.remove(); as you step through this in debug you can see what each item is perhaps this will give you an indication of what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The find function doesn't work with html like '`<span>Android</span>`' you have to use .find("span:contains('Android')").

See the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/ewkfLdsv/

```
$('#device_type_list li input').change(function(){
  var response = $('label[for="' + this.id + '"]').text();
  var device = $('<span>' + response + '</span>');
  if(this.checked){
    $('#device_filter_summary').append(device); 
  } else {
    $('#device_filter_summary').find('span:contains("' + response + '")').remove();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks... I had tried that but my syntax was off. I just had contains(response) which didn't work.

Comment: Your fiddle is great. Here's another with the same thing. http://jsfiddle.net/kirkbross/9jr3v5hq/1/

Answer (score 1):

There is a reason why .remove() is not working because your are finding entire span tag from starting to end of span tag which is wrong. You just have to find "" tag inside .find() then remove it. Like::

```
$('#device_filter_summary').find('span').remove();
```

Comment: Thanks... but this removes all the spans and I need it to only remove the one in question.